# Force a StringFormat result into an "object" target type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, string-formatting

I am trying to use `StringFormat` instead of a Converter to present some text in a DevExpress grid column header, sourced from a `MultiBinding.`

The `Header` property is of type `object` but StringFormat requires the target type to be of type `string.`

I tried using a `TextBlock` as a wrapper, whose `Text` property is `string,` but this caused issues with exporting the grid to Excel - the column header becomes invalid. I tried writing a custom `DataTemplate` to fix the export, struggled, and instead would like to explore the following:

I want to create a custom type that can be used like this:

```
<dxg:GridColumn.Header>
    <local:XamlStringWrapper>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
            <Binding Path="Prop1" />
            <Binding Path="Prop2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </local:XamlStringWrapper>
</dxg:GridColumn.Header>
```

So it would accept the result of the `StringFormat` but in addition would also act like a `string` from the point of view of the column Header... so that if I access `GridColumn.Header` I would get an object of type `string.` And so the export would work correctly.

My attempt is this:

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class XamlStringWrapper : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content",
                                    typeof (string),
                                    typeof (XamlStringWrapper),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Content
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // When the column Header "reads" this object, does it always pull from ToString?
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Content;
    }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? It's not really working with the above (simplified) code - the column header is blank in the app, and invalid in the excel export, although some interesting things are happening in the debugger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) to create a string format converter on the fly:

```xml
<dxg:GridColumn.Header>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{me:StringFormat {}{0}:{1}}">
        <Binding Source="Cake"/>
        <Binding Source="Lie"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</dxg:GridColumn.Header>
```

```cs
public class StringFormatExtension : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public string FormatString { get; private set; }

    public StringFormatExtension(string formatString)
    {
        if (formatString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("formatString");

        FormatString = formatString;
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format(FormatString, values);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work when exporting the data to an Excell spreadsheet?

Comment: @nano: Why not? The binding will return a string.

Comment: Ah that's really neat. I knew that a converter could extend MarkupExtension to shorten the XAML a bit, but didn't know about the "Extension" suffix convention or being able to take constructor arguments from the XAML. Works well, thank you.